# How to split rows in dataframe based on specific names in python?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have a dataframe with below structure:

```
Bronze  Age              0-30   31-60   60+
Country State   Region          
A         X     R1       100    200     300
B         Y     R2       150    220     140
Silver  Age             0-30    31-60   60+
Country State   Region          
A        X      R1      150     220     167
B        Y      R2      735     398     239
Gold    Age             0-30    31-60   60+
Country State   Region          
A        X      R1      232    564     878
B        Y      R2      112    233     543
Platinum    Age         0-30    31-60   60+
Country State   Region          
A        X      R1      646   756      323
B        Y      R2      434   877      978
```

Now, I want to separate each of the category like bronze, silver, gold and platinum into 4 different dataframes.

Sample for bronze output is:

```
Country State   Region  Age   Count     
A         X     R1      0-30    100
A         X     R1      31-60   200
A         X     R1      60+     300
B         Y     R2      0-30    150
B         Y     R2      31-60   220
B         Y     R2      60+     140
```

I am new to python and could not get any idea on how to do this kind of row split.

Comment: Could you share the pandas dataframe in an executable form?

Comment: Can u please share proper dataframe ...I am not understanding ur df structure

Comment: Please check the df image in link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new column for distiguish `ages`,  then use `mask` by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) `names` by forward filling method:

```
df['ages'] = df.iloc[:,0]

ages = ['Bronze','Silver','Gold', 'Platinum']
mask = df.ages.isin(ages)

df['ages'] = df.ages[mask]
df['ages'] = df.ages.fillna(method='ffill')
#print df

#print df.iloc[1,:].fillna(df.iloc[0,:])
df.columns = df.iloc[1,:].fillna(df.iloc[0,:])

df = df.dropna().rename(columns={'Bronze':'Ages'})

print df 
1  Country State Region 0-30 31-60  60+      Ages
2        A     X     R1  100   200  300    Bronze
3        B     Y     R2  150   220  140    Bronze
6        A     X     R1  150   220  167    Silver
7        B     Y     R2  735   398  239    Silver
10       A     X     R1  232   564  878      Gold
11       B     Y     R2  112   233  543      Gold
14       A     X     R1  646   756  323  Platinum
15       B     Y     R2  434   877  978  Platinum
```

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshaping, then sort DataFrame by column `Country` with function [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, 
             id_vars=['Country','State','Region', 'Ages'], 
             var_name='Age', 
             value_name='Count' )

df = df.sort_values(by=['Country', 'Age'])

print df
   Country State Region      Ages    Age Count
0        A     X     R1    Bronze   0-30   100
2        A     X     R1    Silver   0-30   150
4        A     X     R1      Gold   0-30   232
6        A     X     R1  Platinum   0-30   646
8        A     X     R1    Bronze  31-60   200
10       A     X     R1    Silver  31-60   220
12       A     X     R1      Gold  31-60   564
14       A     X     R1  Platinum  31-60   756
16       A     X     R1    Bronze    60+   300
18       A     X     R1    Silver    60+   167
20       A     X     R1      Gold    60+   878
22       A     X     R1  Platinum    60+   323
1        B     Y     R2    Bronze   0-30   150
3        B     Y     R2    Silver   0-30   735
5        B     Y     R2      Gold   0-30   112
7        B     Y     R2  Platinum   0-30   434
9        B     Y     R2    Bronze  31-60   220
11       B     Y     R2    Silver  31-60   398
13       B     Y     R2      Gold  31-60   233
15       B     Y     R2  Platinum  31-60   877
17       B     Y     R2    Bronze    60+   140
19       B     Y     R2    Silver    60+   239
21       B     Y     R2      Gold    60+   543
23       B     Y     R2  Platinum    60+   978
```

Create dictionary `d` for storing `DataFrames` and fill it:

```
d = {}

for age in ages:
    #print df[df.Ages == age]
    d.update({age : df[df.Ages == age].drop('Ages', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)})

print d['Bronze']  
  Country State Region    Age Count
0       A     X     R1   0-30   100
1       A     X     R1  31-60   200
2       A     X     R1    60+   300
3       B     Y     R2   0-30   150
4       B     Y     R2  31-60   220
5       B     Y     R2    60+   140
print d['Silver']   
  Country State Region    Age Count
0       A     X     R1   0-30   150
1       A     X     R1  31-60   220
2       A     X     R1    60+   167
3       B     Y     R2   0-30   735
4       B     Y     R2  31-60   398
5       B     Y     R2    60+   239
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael.That works.Meanwhile I working on other approaches too.Can we have the age groups in the same order as I mentioned initially in the final dict say d['Bronze']?

Comment: Thats exactly my requirement.Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And you can upvote too. Click to small triangle above `0` above `accepting` mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi something might this might work, not tested. Select based on the multi-index, reset_index and melt.

```
dfBronze =  df.ix["Bronze"].reset_index()
dfBronze =  dfBronze.melt(id_vars=['Country','State','Region'], value_vars=['Age'])
```

Comment: Hi,I get a key error here.To be clear,all this data has got no headers.They are just the content in multiple columns.For bronze df,I need all the information before Silver.Silver should go into different df and likewise others.

Comment: Can you put up your code for generating the dataframe

Comment: Please check the df image in link above.

Comment: From the image I think you would be better with multi-indexing. Is it a scraped table ?

Comment: Yes.It is kind of scraped table only.I cannot reveal the source as it is confidential.Could you please guide me on how to go about your idea?

Comment: I'd say you could do a better scrape of the table first.

Comment: It is read in the same way as I have projected above.Cannot change the format of it.

Comment: is above a toy example or the real thing?

Comment: I have changed the real data to maintain confidentiality,but it is a real thing only.